# Superscript when output to MS Word

Tags: r, ms-word, header, footer

It is very easy to do superscript in SAS in [headers/footnotes](http://support.sas.com/kb/24/046.html) or in [a dataset](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Procedures/Superscript-or-Subscript-in-SAS-dataset/td-p/158183). And it is very useful feature in clinical reporting! Unfortunately, I cannot find it in R.

Now I'm using [officer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/index.html) and [flextable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/overview.html) packages for outputing to MS Word. Is it possible to do superscript and subscript in these packages (or maybe in other packages with similar functionality, like [htmlTable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html)?

[image]

Comment: The context of your question suggests you are using superscripts and superscripts to markup footnotes to tables or pages rather than just applying the subscript or superscript formatting.  In MS Word you can use Footnotes to add numbered annotations to a page which are cross references to the annotation.  Its not so easy to do for Tables where it is usually necessary to set up your own sequence counter and manually insert cross references.

Comment: @Freeflow no references or cross references, just symbols in superscript

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can include header and footers using office package

```
library(officer)

my_doc <- read_docx() 
my_doc <- my_doc %>% 
  body_add_par("Header 1 ", style = "centered") %>% 
  body_add_par("Header 2 ", style = "centered") %>% 
  body_add_par("Header 3 ", style = "centered") %>% 
  body_add_par("Header 4", style = "Normal") %>%   
  body_add_table(dataframe, style = "Normal Table") %>%  
  cursor_forward() %>%
  body_add_par("Footer 1,
               OTH=Other", style = "toc 1") %>%
  body_end_section(landscape = TRUE)

print(my_doc, target = "output.docx")
```

Comment: Thank you for yor answer! Creation of a header and a footer is not a problem - I need to do superscript in any place of data frame (flextable), e.g. in any cell in header, footer or body of table.

Comment: @VladimirMladov please follow the link to get the same https://rpubs.com/brouwern/superscript

Comment: Arun, I saw this page yesterday. :) Unfortunately, `Markdown` is not appropriate in my case. I try to solve this sudden problem without using it.

Answer (score 0):

please provide an example of data you want to apply super and subscript to.
In general you can use latex markup with .rmd files and render it to word file like:

```
$$text_{subscript}$$
$$text^{superscript}$$
```

Comment: `officer` does not use Rmd files.

Comment: @Omar113 thank you for your answer. `Markdown` and `Rmd` files are not appropriate for `officer` or `flextable` packages. I need to do superscript in any place (a cell in header, footer or body) of any data frame (or tibble). Now I use `officer` package for output. Before it I used `ReporteRs` package. So, my question is about special symbol or sequence of symbols like `^{super 2}` in SAS which is identified as content in superscript (e.g., `X^{super 2}` means `X^2` where "2" is the superscript in MS Word document).

Comment: @VladimirMladov that's wrong, flextable is working perfectly with R markdown

Comment: @DavidGohel What is the solution then? How can one express markup like superscript in dataframe with flextable?

Comment: @Omar113 I was only correcting the assertion *Markdown and Rmd files are not appropriate for flextable*. the question is crossposted and already got an answer here: https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/issues/113